Ubuntu OS not loaded after upgrading
Recently I have upgraded my Ubuntu system to 24.04 version from 22.04.
The system could not properly load the OS after trying with upgrading commands.
Below are the attached screenshots for the same issue.
EFI: Ubuntu (TOSHİBA MQ04ABF100)
boot information
boot configuration
boot security 
booting options

Welcome to AskUbuntu! The images you’ve shared are all for the UEFI, and do not show the reason for why the machine might fail its boot sequence. Are there any messages shown when Ubuntu tries to start?

Hi Matigo, Thank you for responding back. There is no others messages for this issue.

What happens past the UEFI screen? Just a blank screen with no error messages? If so, please fresh install Ubuntu 24.04. You can use the live session to backup any data present in the home partition.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Now I could see in boot option menu as below:  Ubuntu (TOSHIBA MQ04ABF100) SATA HDD: (TOSHIBA MQ04ABF100)

What happens if you choose Ubuntu?
